# What is recursive enums and syntax inderect in swift

Tags: swift2

Swift 2.0 has new feature called indirectly recursive enum. Can someone explain what it is?

Answer (score 3):

From [Swift Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID536)

> A recursive enumeration is an enumeration that has another instance of the enumeration as the associated value for one or more of the enumeration cases.

The example given highlights a simplified use case:

```
indirect enum ArithmeticExpression {
    case Number(Int)
    case Addition(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
    case Multiplication(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
}

func evaluate(expression: ArithmeticExpression) -> Int {
    switch expression {
        case .Number(let value):
            return value
        case .Addition(let left, let right):
            return evaluate(left) + evaluate(right)
        case .Multiplication(let left, let right):
            return evaluate(left) * evaluate(right)
    }
}

// evaluate (5 + 4) * 2
let five = ArithmeticExpression.Number(5)
let four = ArithmeticExpression.Number(4)
let sum = ArithmeticExpression.Addition(five, four)
let product = ArithmeticExpression.Multiplication(sum, ArithmeticExpression.Number(2))
print(evaluate(product))
// prints "18"
```